# Hibernate corretamente configurado não insere no banco de dados

Tags: java, java-ee, hibernate

Meu código não insere no banco de dados `Mysql`. Ele identifica tudo o database, as tabelas e os campos, mas a inserção não é feita.

### UsuarioDAO.java

```
package br.com.sistec.dao;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

import br.com.sistec.domain.Usuario;
import br.com.sistec.util.HibernateUtil;

public class UsuarioDAO {


    public void salvar(Usuario usuario){

        Session sessao = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction transacao = null;

        try{

            transacao = sessao.beginTransaction();
            sessao.save(usuario);
            transacao.commit();


        }catch (Exception ex){
            if(transacao != null){

                transacao.rollback();

            }


        }

            finally{

                sessao.close();
            }
        }



    }
```

### HibernateUtil.java

```
package br.com.sistec.util;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;

public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {

            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.configure();

            ServiceRegistry serviceregistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                    .applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();

            SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration
                    .buildSessionFactory(serviceregistry);

            return sessionFactory;

        }

        catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

}
```

### Usuario.java

```
package br.com.sistec.domain;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name ="tbl_usuario")
public class Usuario {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "cpo_usuid")
    private Long codigo;

    @Column(name = "cpo_usuusuario", length = 40, nullable = false)
    private String usuario;

    @Column(name = "cpo_ususenha", length = 10, nullable = false)
    private String senha;

    public Long getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(Long codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public String getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }

    public void setUsuario(String usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }

    public String getSenha() {
        return senha;
    }

    public void setSenha(String senha) {
        this.senha = senha;
    }
```

### UsuarioDAOTest.java

```
package br.com.sistec.test;

import org.junit.Test;

import br.com.sistec.dao.UsuarioDAO;
import br.com.sistec.domain.Usuario;

public class UsuarioDAOTest {

        @Test
        public void salvar(){

            Usuario u1 = new Usuario();
            u1.setUsuario("Teste");


            Usuario u2 = new Usuario();
            u2.setUsuario("Teste");


            UsuarioDAO usuDao = new UsuarioDAO();

            usuDao.salvar(u1);
            usuDao.salvar(u2);


    }


}
```

### hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_sistec</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">fatec</property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect</property>

        <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>


        <mapping class="br.com.sistec.domain.Usuario"/>


    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

Alguém me ajuda?

Comment: Já tentou debuggar? Ele chega a entrar no `catch` do Salvar?

Comment: não lançou nenhuma exception, correto? só não persiste?

Comment: isso mesmo ele nao lança nenhum exception, o Junit informa que o metodo salvar esta correto e fica tudo verde,ele identifica as tabelas identifica tudo mas a inserção não é feita.

Comment: É mostrado algum SQL de INSERT no console da aplicação? Ou apenas enxerga apenas SELECTs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bem, vamos lá:

1. Não está aparecendo o erro pois você não esta fazendo nada com a `exception`, tente colocar um `ex.printStackTrace();` no seu método salvar que fica no `DAO` que você ira encontrar o erro.
2. O problema é bem simples, no model você colocou a seguinte
   propriedade no atributo senha: `@Column(name = "cpo_ususenha",length = 10, nullable = false)`. Ou seja, você está dizendo que esse
   atributo não pode ser nulo. Note que você não
   passa um valor pra ele no seu Teste.

Para resolver o problema voce pode mapear esse atributo como `nullable = true` ou então passar um valor pra ele, ex:

```
u1.setSenha("senha1");
```

Answer (score -3):

```
import br.com.sistec.domain.Usuario;
import br.com.sistec.util.HibernateUtil;

public class UsuarioDAO {

 private  Session sessao;

 private Transaction transacao = null;

  public UsuarioDAO(){
        sessao = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
  }  

    public void salvar(Usuario usuario){


        try{

            transacao = sessao.beginTransaction();
            sessao.save(usuario);
            transacao.commit();


        }catch (Exception ex){
            if(transacao != null){

                transacao.rollback();

            }


        }

            finally{

                sessao.close();
            }
        }



    }
```

Outra opção para seu Teste de unidade.

```
package br.com.sistec.test;

import org.junit.Test;

import br.com.sistec.dao.UsuarioDAO;
import br.com.sistec.domain.Usuario;

public class UsuarioDAOTest {

        @Test
        public void salvar(){

        try{

           Session sessao = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

           Transaction transacao = sessao.beginTransaction();

           Usuario u1 = new Usuario();

           u1.setUsuario("Teste");


            Usuario u2 = new Usuario();
            u2.setUsuario("Teste");

            sessao.save(u1);
            sessao.save(u2);

            transacao.commit();

          } catch(Exception e){

             e.printStackTrace();

           }

    }
```

Comment: Olá Marcos. O que o seu código está fazendo diferente do código do OP? (Além de mover a sessão e a transação para escopo da classe)? Como esse seu pedaço de código responde a pergunta do OP?

Comment: Isso só ele pode responder.

Comment: @Marcos não entendo, como só "ele" pode responder? O que o  Anthony quer saber é em que a sua resposta resolve o problema? Como você chegou a esta solução? O porque isto possivelmente resolveria o problema? Recomendo que leia este link do FAQ: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer  Ser breve é aceitável, mas explicações mais completas são melhores. (não fui eu quem negativou a sua resposta, mas se você edita-la e deixar mais completa eu te dou +1 pra dar um up ;) - Espero que entenda isto tudo como uma critica construtiva!

Comment: Obrigado pela sua sugestão.Críticas construtivas são sempre bem-vindas !!