# Criar Tabelas com Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Boa tarde !!

Sou novo com o Hibernate e estou a dois dias tentando implementa a criação de tabelas com ele, já segui vários tutoriais, mas não funciona.

Alguém pode me ajudar ?

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC 
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" 
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

<session-factory>

    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="connection.drive_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/testebanco</property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password">102030</property>

    <!-- JDBC connection pool(use the built-in) -->
    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</property>

    <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    <!-- Disable the second-level cache -->
    <property     name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>

    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

    <!-- Mapeamento das entidades -->
    <mapping class="teste.DAO.Estado" />

</session-factory>
```

Class de criação de sessões:

```
 public class HibernateUtil {
 private static SessionFactory sf = createSessionFactory();

public static SessionFactory getSf() {
    return sf;
}

private static SessionFactory createSessionFactory(){
    try{
        Configuration cfg = new Configuration().configure();

        ServiceRegistry registro = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(cfg.getProperties()).build();

        SessionFactory f = cfg.buildSessionFactory(registro);

        return f;
    }catch(Throwable ex){
        System.err.println("Erro ao criar a sessão " + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }

}
}
```

Estou usando o JUnit para realizar os teste:

```
public class HibernateUtilTeste {

@Test
public void conectar(){
    Session sessao =  HibernateUtil.getSf().openSession();
    sessao.close();
    HibernateUtil.getSf().close();
}
}
```

Classe estado:

```
@Entity
 @Table
 public class Estado extends GenericID {

private String nome;
private String sigla;

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}
public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}
public String getSigla() {
    return sigla;
}
public void setSigla(String sigla) {
    this.sigla = sigla;
}
```

Classe de ID

```
 @SuppressWarnings("serial")
  @MappedSuperclass
 public class GenericID implements Serializable {

 @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}   
}
```

**Log**:

> Log ---------
>       jul 09, 2016 2:04:51 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.1.Final} jul 09, 2016 2:04:51 PM
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Environment  INFO: HHH000206:
>   hibernate.properties not found jul 09, 2016 2:04:51 PM
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider INFO: HHH000021:
>   Bytecode provider name : javassist jul 09, 2016 2:04:51 PM
>   org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.stax.LocalXmlResourceResolver
>   resolveEntity WARN: HHH90000012: Recognized obsolete hibernate
>   namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration.
>   Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration
>   instead.  Support for obsolete DTD/XSD namespaces may be removed at
>   any time. jul 09, 2016 2:04:51 PM
>   org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager
>    INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations
>   {5.0.1.Final} jul 09, 2016 2:04:51 PM
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
>   configure WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool
>   (not for production use!) jul 09, 2016 2:04:51 PM
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
>   buildCreator INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [null] at URL
>   [jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/testebanco] jul 09, 2016 2:04:51 PM
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
>   buildCreator INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=root,
>   drive_class=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver, password=****} jul 09, 2016 2:04:51
>   PM
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
>   buildCreator INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false jul 09, 2016
>   2:04:51 PM
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections
>    INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 1 (min=1) Sat
>   Jul 09 14:04:52 BRT 2016 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without
>   server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL
>   5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance
>   with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate
>   property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL
>   by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for
>   server certificate verification. jul 09, 2016 2:04:52 PM
>   org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect  INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect:
>   org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect jul 09, 2016 2:04:52 PM
>   org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl
>   applyImportSources INFO: HHH000476: Executing import script
>   'org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ScriptSourceInputNonExistentImpl@45385f75'
>   jul 09, 2016 2:04:53 PM
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl
>   stop INFO: HHH10001008: Cleaning up connection pool
>   [jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/testebanco]

Comment: Adicione na sua pergunta o que você já conseguiu fazer.

Comment: Como ta sua classe Estado?

Comment: Uma abordagem que você pode seguir: utilize algum quick start, que inicialize um projeto, já com os artefatos de persistência prontos. Uma das formas fáceis é utilizando a perspectiva Java EE, dinamic web project(maven). Depois disso, veja como foi implementado.

Comment: Eu estou usando o Maven, quando rodo o projeto ela não gera erro nem um, mais também não cria a tabela.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/71578/hibernate-corretamente-configurado-n%c3%a3o-insere-no-banco-de-dados/102019#102019

Comment: O banco de dados **testebanco** já existe? O hibernate só consegue criar as tabelas se o banco já existir.

Comment: tive que postar aqui porque nao tenho bastantes pontos ainda pra comentar , mas esse tutorial aqui esta bem explicado , nao sei se vc ja tentou ele . [Hibernate Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/)